# Regex pattern matching specific word

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a text input on my html page. When a user tries to add a new watch I want it to start with WATCH_XXXX (X's are whatever the user inputs). It has to start with WATCH_ all caps with the underscore. I've tried a lot of different ways but I keep getting the "please match the requested format" pop-up. This was the last one I tried -> required pattern="^WATCH_[a-z]". Am I even close to getting this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex `^WATCH_[a-zA-Z]+$` should work

```html
<form>
  <input required pattern="^WATCH_[a-zA-Z]+$"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It did! Could you please explain to me whats going on? How does that work

Comment: it match upper and lower case letters [a-zA-Z] and plus match any number of them and $ make that it match whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Do all characters after "WATCH_" have to be letters? If not `^WATCH_.*` may work better.

Tested here: https://regex101.com/#javascript

Also a great learning tool I use for Regex: http://regexone.com/

Comment: Yes they do have to be letters however, I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the resources!